# Multiselect month from table - sqlite

Tags: java, sql, sqlite

I get 1-n selected months from a JList. 
Now I'd like to select rows from a sqlite DB with the selected months.

Is there a way to do it the easy way to build the select string, e.g. with a loop and a LIKE statement?

```
resultSet = statement
        .executeQuery("SELECT sum(Betrag) FROM record WHERE strftime('%Y',Datum)='"
            + options.getList_years().get(options.getCurrent_year_index())
            + "' AND strftime('%m',Datum) LIKE '"
            + "02 || 04 || 12"  //Here are the months, 
            + "' AND Sektion LIKE '"
            + "%"
            + "' AND Inhaber LIKE '"
            + list_accounts.getSelectedValue()
            + "' AND Ausgabe='"
            + "true';");
```

Or has it to look that way?

```
strftime('%m',Datum)='02' OR strftime('%m',Datum)='04' OR trftime('%m',Datum)='12'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use an IN clause:

```
... AND strftime('%m',Datum) IN ('02', '04', '12')
```

But you should definitely not use string concatenation to set parameters dynamically in your query. This is the best way to suffer from SQL injection attacks. Use prepared statements, with a `?` placeholder for each of your parameter:

```
SELECT sum(Betrag) FROM record WHERE strftime('%Y',Datum) = ? ...
```

Learn more about prepared statements in [the JDBC tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html).

You will indeed have to use some loop or utility to build the IN clause. `StringUtils` from commons-lang is useful here:

```
"... AND strftime('%m',Datum) IN (" + StringUtils.repeat("?", ", ", months.size())
```